# Get stats only for certain columns of a given data in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like below

**dataframe**

```
date                               location      cpu    mem                 drops   upload   download
2018-02-11 04:05:33.438948+05:30    DEL           44    23                      5   14.5        44.51       
2018-02-11 04:05:37.905242+05:30    MUM            0    23                   6.08   5.1         0       
2018-02-11 17:09:47.211344+05:30    DEL           24    34                   4.19   19.4        37.53   
2018-02-11 17:10:13.553385+05:30    KOL           23    35                   4.47   11.5        46.34
```

I need to display data on hourly basis for all hours for the specified date but only for certain columns.

What I did is

```
hourly_stats = df.resample('H').agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)
```

It gives me the stats for all the columns.But I need to get stats only for `cpu` and `drops`.

I tried doing something like this but doesn't work

```
hourly_stats = df.groupby(['cpu', 'drops']).resample('H').agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)
```

How do I get statistics on hourly basis only for the specified column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter columns after `resample` or before by subset:

```
hourly_stats = df.resample('H')['cpu', 'drops'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)
```

Or:

```
hourly_stats = df[['cpu', 'drops']].resample('H').agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)
```

Comment: this is what I needed.Thanks!

Comment: hey I have posted another question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854444/calculate-percentage-difference-for-the-stats-of-two-given-dates-in-pandas] Can you help me with this one?

Comment: @SouvikRay - I check it, but not idea about solution. Sorry :(